# Looking for a young adult novel, gemstones for eyes

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, magic

I’m in search of a single young adult novel in which the main character is a young woman, she’s been training in an academy of girls, learning how to fight (and possibly use magic?) She comes of age and there is a ceremony where her eyes are replaced with gemstones, I believe they were obsidian but amber or garnet are also sticking out in my mind. She goes on a journey where she meets a man (and later there is a romance between them). They are on a boat at one point, she senses a monster or wizard and uses magic to defeat them. At the end of the book she uses the power of her gemstone eyes to speak to a council of people about something important, then can’t turn off the power and it slowly drives her mad. A former witch (sorceress?) finds her and manages to remove the stones and gives her blue eyes. I think one of the names starts with an s, could be wrong. I read this around 2015, the cover was, I believe, a young woman with gemstone eyes. Perhaps a golden background.
Any and all help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 6):

This might be [*Hawkspar*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?714889) (2008) by Holly Lisle.

The [summary on Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1492132.Hawkspar) describes how the slaves of the order can be chosen to receive magical eyes of stone, and the protagonist gains the power to see through time.

[A sample chapter](https://hollylisle.com/hawkspar/) on the author's site introduces us to a convent-like setting whose female "penitents" are taught martial arts and other skills, and to the magically-endowed leaders who are called "Obsidians."

Comment: Yes, this is it. I have the book and it matches the description.

Comment: Worth noting that the "witch" who turns up in the last couple of pages is the main character from the previous book in the series "Talyn" - strongly suggest reading that book before Hawkspar.